# Executable .jar - works for some users, but not others

Tags: java, jar, executable-jar

I recently released an application in the form of a .jar file (built using Eclipse's "Export Runnable Jar File", using Java JRE 6). Most users are able to double click the file and have it run properly, but a few have reported that double clicking the file causes javaw to start, and immediately exit (with no error message).

I have talked with a few users, and walked them through the process of running the .jar from the command line. The users with the issue seem to be getting "Main class not found" errors, even though the .jar has a META-INF folder with a properly formatted MANIFEST.MF file inside.

Is there anything I can do to insure the program will run properly? Is the issue more likely in my program, or in their Java environment?

Thank you.

Comment: Have them run `java -version`, the may have a pre 1.6 java as their default.

Comment: If the problem is versioning, launch the app. using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info)/`deployJava.js`.  That combo. will ensure the user has has a version equal to or greater than the version needed to run the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JAR is non-executable file format and its extension might be not associated with Java. Its better use open source tools like [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/) or [JSmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/) to wrap your JAR as an executable file. This way makes your application more user friendly.

Comment: Launch4j worked like a charm, and was very easy to set up. Thank you for the suggestion!